# Help me to remove the error in my program?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class math
{
    JFrame jf;
    JTextField jt;
    JButton jb;
    JButton jb1;
    math()
    {
        jf=new JFrame("frame");
        jf.setSize(200,200);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jt=new JTextField(50);
        jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton jb=new JButton("30");
        JButton jb1=new JButton("sin");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                jt.setText("30");
            }
        });
        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                String s=jt.getText();
                double x=Double.parseDouble(s);
                double s1=Math.sin(x);
                jt.setText(s1);
            }
        });
        JButton jb2=new JButton("cos");
        jf.add(jt);
        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(jb1);
        jf.add(jb2);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new math();
    }
}
//its giving error that double can't be applied to jt.setText
```

Comment: What is the full exception that the program is throwing?

Comment: Use `jt.setText(s1+"");` or `jt.setText(String.valueOf(s1));`

Comment: OP posted a follow-up question, but it got closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476258/program-is-not-giving-desired-output

Answer (score 5):

The `setText` method takes a `String`, not a `double`.

You can get a string out of your `double` by calling  `Double.toString(someDouble)`.

Answer (score 2):

[`javax.swing.text.JTextField.setText(java.lang.String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a `String`. You can get a `String` representation of `s1` by writing this:

`jt.setText(Double.toString(s1));`

Now, arguably

`jt.setText(String.valueOf(s1));`

or

`jt.setText(s1 + "");`

are better choices because neither will require a change if you refactor `s1` to be of some other type.

Personally, I've always found the third choice, string concatenation with the empty string, to be a bit of an inelegant hack.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, I think:

```
double s1=Math.sin(x);
jt.setText(s1);
```

The "setText()" method doesn't want a double for an argument, as you're giving it here; it wants a String. So convert your double to a String, and it will work:

```
double s1=Math.sin(x);
jt.setText(String.valueOf(s1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**setText**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) method of the `TextComponent` class expects its argument to be of type `String` so the double you are trying to pass to it needs to be converted to a String.

Change

```
jt.setText(s1);
```

to

```
jt.setText(Double.toString(s1));
```