# Program is not giving desired output

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class math
{
    JFrame jf;
    JTextField jt;
    JButton jb;
    JButton jb1;
    math()
    {
        jf=new JFrame("frame");
        jf.setSize(200,200);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jt=new JTextField(50);
        jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton jb=new JButton("30");
        JButton jb1=new JButton("sin");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                jt.setText("90");
            }
        });
        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                String s=jt.getText();
                float x=Float.parseFloat(s);
                double s1=Math.sin(x);
                String s2=String.valueOf(s1);
                jt.setText(s2);
            }
        });
        JButton jb2=new JButton("cos");
        jf.add(jt);
        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(jb1);
        jf.add(jb2);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new math();
    }
}
//output errors=sin(90)=0.89999 and sin(any angle) is coming incorrect
```

Comment: What is your exact question?  What is your expected output for specific input?

Comment: seems your question is not swing related? so why not remove the swing related code, people will be more happy to tackle on problems which have less unrelated information :).

Comment: Belongs on [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/).

Comment: The sine function expects input in radians, not degrees. So sin(90) *does* equal about .9.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473018/help-me-to-remove-the-error-in-my-program, an earlier post by the OP with almost identical code

Answer (score 1):

`Math.sin()` accepts angle in the form of PI representation.

Use  to get expected result

```
Math.sin(Math.PI/2.0);
```

Comment: i am making calculator in java.so how can user enter PI everytime

Comment: convert degree to radian form